# How can I change the default screen resolution?

Tags: resolution, screen, default, xbmc

Here's the scoop: I have a crappy VisionQuest TV that I am currently using as a monitor on my computer running XBMCbuntu. It defaults to 1280x768 which the TV will not display correctly. It appears to be the correct size, but the screen is panned WAY to the left. The TV works fine on 1024x768 with the screen sitting in the right spot. Problem is, I have to change the resolution to 1024x768 every  time I boot up.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu you are using?

Answer (score 8):

create `.xprofile` in your home directory.

```
gedit .xprofile
```

and paste line,

```
xrandr --output TV --mode 1024x768 --rate 60
```

Save file now give execution permission

```
chmod +x .xprofile
```

Comment: If I don't see "xprofile", should I make the file? I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 5):

[image] Search for Display in Unity. You can set your screen resolution here.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what login manager you use, since you didn't specify that.

GDM uses the xorg file to determine resolution.
Anyway in Xorg you have multiple resolutions, the first one is used as default.
So you could try to edit your xorg.conf and put 1024x768 as the the first resolution (the priorities go from left to right).

You can also remove resolution you dont't want.

```
SubSection "Display"
    Depth       24
    Modes       "1024x768" "1280x768"
EndSubSection
```

EndSection