# Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS unable to change resolution

Tags: display-resolution

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (updated 2 days ago from 16). The resolution was fine, but accidentally it changed to 1024x768 (4:3) and every time I try to change to 1920x1080 (or any other size) it is not accepted and returns to 1024x768 (4:3).

[image: Apply Changes? Display settings]

[image: Choosing resolution]

[image: Keep changes popup]

Tried several times, restarted pc, but no changes applied. Please help:)

Existing resolutions:

[image: Screnshot of terminal showing 1920x1080 as max resolution available]

Comment: have you look here https://askubuntu.com/questions/281509/how-do-i-change-the-screen-resolution-using-ubuntu-command-line/398740

Comment: Yes, i tried to make a commands, using terminal but with no success

Comment: You can try this, I hope that it can help. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096629/change-ubuntu-server-18-04-lts-bionic-console-screen-resolution

Answer (score 3):

Check if **"nomodeset"** is added in your grub. (Like in my case)

goto `/etc/default/grub`

If yes remove it.

Run command after saving file

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot the system

Comment: Can you please explain what `nomodeset` does?

Comment: Adding nomodeset doesn’t load amdgpu driver which comes with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

*First check your monitor code*

`echo $DISPLAY`

*Check your device code*

`sudo lspci |grep -i vga`

*i solved this problem by configure xorg the solution is creating configuration file in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf`*

*The 10-monitor.conf should be contain the configuration like this:*

`Section "Monitor"`

```
    Identifier  "Monitor0"`
```

`EndSection`

`Section "Device"`

```
    Identifier  "Device0"`

    Driver      "radeon"
```

`EndSection`

`Section "Screen"`

```
    Identifier "Screen0"  #Collapse Monitor and Device section to Screen section
    Device                 "Device0"
    Monitor                "Monitor0"
    SubSection             "Display"
        Depth              16
        Modes              "1920x1080_60.00" #Choose the resolution
EndSubSection
```

`EndSection`

*Goodluck*

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, in the guest's Terminal:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktop`

https://communities.vmware.com/message/2567255#2567255

Answer (score 0):

it also happened to me. I thought how come without any update or change?. then checked the cables and bingo. it returned to normal resolution.

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem was and how exactly you corrected it?