# Single display unable to set 5120x1440 resolution

Tags: xorg, display, intel-graphics, display-resolution, intel

I was running Ubuntu 19.04 with a Philips 499P9H 5k monitor that was running at 5120x1440 at 70Hz. Today I upgraded to Ubuntu 19.10 and can now only run the monitor at 3840x1080 at 60Hz.

The option for 5120x1440 is available however when I select it I just get the same 3840x1080.

I remember previously I had to run `X -configure` and copy the config to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. However the file still existed from before and even after running that again there was no difference and I can still only run at 3840x1080.

The monitor is connected via display port and I the GPU is an `Intel HD Graphics 530`. As I mentioned, this did work before the upgrade but doesn't anymore.

Screenshot of `xrandr` listing the supported modes:

[image: Screenshot of xrandr listing the supported modes]

Comment: I can see that in the output of `~/.local/share/xorg/xorg.0.log` there is the following output: `[    40.969] (EE) intel(0): failed to set mode: Invalid argument [22]`

Comment: I re-installed Ubuntu 19.04 and all seems to work again

Answer (score 3):

For those finding this now, these steps worked on Intel Iris Graphics 540 and 5120x1440 on a Samsung G9.

Modifying the commands used here - [How do I change the screen resolution using Ubuntu command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281509/how-do-i-change-the-screen-resolution-using-ubuntu-command-line)

Create a mode string for 5120x1440 at 30HZ (I'm using HDMI and HDMI 1.4 supports 30HZ only at 5120x1440)

```
$ cvt 5120 1440 30

# 5120x1440 29.96 Hz (CVT) hsync: 43.98 kHz; pclk: 292.75 MHz
Modeline "5120x1440_30.00"  292.75  5120 5360 5888 6656  1440 1443 1453 1468 -hsync +vsync
```

Copy everything after Modeline and for xrandr, like this:

```
$ sudo xrandr --newmode "5120x1440_30.00" 292.75  5120 5360 5888 6656  1440 1443 1453 1468 -hsync +vsync
```

Find the current display, in my case HDMI-1 is returned:

```
$ xrandr | grep -e " connected [^(]" | sed -e "s/\([A-Z0-9]\+\) connected.*/\1/"
HDMI-1
```

Add the mode to the display (replace HDMI-1 with whatever was returned from the last command):

```
$ sudo xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 5120x1440_30.00
```

You can now change the resolution to the new mode in the graphics settings (or change by command line).

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you for the step-by-step.

G9 Odyssey + Dell XPS 13 Dev w/ Ubuntu 20.04 (HDMI to DP)

Comment: Worked as well, but it didn't remember it after reboot. Also after reboot the new mode is gone. Using KDE. How can I make Ubuntu to remember this resolution?