# After setting display resolution 5120x1440 I get current resolution 7040 x 1700 (Ubuntu 22.04.3, Philips 45B1U6900C, Dell Inspiron 14 5410)

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.3 on a Dell Inspiron 14 5410.

When connecting a new Philips 45B1U6900C monitor, the correct resolution 5120x1440 was not listed, so I created it, following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183735/single-display-unable-to-set-5120x1440-resolution)

Here's the detail:

```
$ cvt 5120 1440 30
# 5120x1440 29.96 Hz (CVT) hsync: 43.98 kHz; pclk: 292.75 MHz
Modeline "5120x1440_30.00"  292.75  5120 5360 5888 6656  1440 1443 1453 1468 -hsync +vsync

$ sudo xrandr --newmode "5120x1440_30.00" 292.75  5120 5360 5888 6656  1440 1443 1453 1468 -hsync +vsync

$ sudo xrandr --addmode DVI-I-2-1 5120x1440_30.00

$ xrandr --listactivemonitors
Monitors: 2
 0: +*eDP-1 1920/309x1080/173+5120+620  eDP-1
 1: +DVI-I-2-1 5120/1090x1440/310+0+0  DVI-I-2-1
```

so, apparently, it worked, but...

```
$ xrandr|head -n1
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 7040 x 1700, maximum 16384 x 16384
```

the resolution is 7040x1700 and the screen "overflows" the physical boundaries of the monitor, also with an incorrect aspect ratio (everything appears squeezed)

Any ideas how to solve this ?
(I tried 30Hz to be on the safe side of HDMI but also tried 75Hz with same result)