# Display got messed up, can't see most of the screen

Tags: display-resolution

A completely new Linux / Ubuntu user here, I installed Ubuntu alongside with Windows 10, had problems getting it running because of my Nvidia GeForce 1050 mobile graphics card, but nomodeset edit in grub got it running until I installed my drivers. Got the drivers running too, everything looked and worked fine, but after one reboot all I could see was the top left corner of screen. Tried uninstalling my driver but it made it even worse and more zoomed in to the corner. Now it's even crashing if I touch anything but the terminal.

Here's how it looks now:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuDyk.jpg

Any idea what to do now? Don't even know how to google this properly... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[1] With xrandr:

[How do I change the screen resolution using Ubuntu command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281509/how-do-i-change-the-screen-resolution-using-ubuntu-command-line/398740)

[2]
Start the console (lalt+f2 or win+f2 or rescue mode from your install media).
Check "Monitor" section in /etc/X11/xorg.conf. Are there any exotic resolutions listed? Put single entry, pretty much obvious for your setup. Try "man xorg.conf" to get you started. xorg-server also has a small tool that should calculate VESA resolution entries for your monitor.

```
cvt -r 1280 1024 60
```

produces

```
Modeline "1280x1024R"   90.75  1280 1328 1360 1440  1024 1027 1034 1054 +hsync -vsync
```

Put the Modeline into monitor section (but don't copy/paste above one). With just a single entry, X should stuck with it.

[3]
Depending on your desktop environment (kde/gnome/lxde/ etc.) resolution might be set in user's profile. Try adding different user and log in with it. Is resolution the same? Refer each of mentioned GUI-s...