# Help - Ubuntu in VirtualBox only upper left corner visible

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox

I get a view like this, mouse is doubled and it's impossible to do anything. Can somebody help me resolve this? I wanted to try to install guest additions, but I can't because of the view like this either... And of course restarting doesn't help this...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've finally got to a normal view by doing:

1. Hitting Windows Key and typing terminal, clicking enter on the keyboard
2. then typing xrandr -q | less to get the monitor/output name and available resolutions
3. I ran xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode 1440x900

This helped me reset the view. Then I changed display scaling to 100% in display settings.

That trick with xrandr I found from this question:

[How do I change the screen resolution using Ubuntu command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281509/how-do-i-change-the-screen-resolution-using-ubuntu-command-line)

If anybody wants to enhance why this has happened in the first place and how to ensure this really never happens again - feel free.