# How to change screen aspect ratio from bash?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, display, display-resolution

So I have Ubuntu installed on a motherboard, which I connect to, two different displays back and forth. It's a little painful to manually change the settings every time, so I want to write a bash script which will be inside `/usr/local/bin/`, so that I can access it easily.

I want to know the terminal command for the following. (I might pass the "resolution/aspect-ratio" as bash argument for example)

> Settings > Display > Resolution > Choose > Apply > Confirm

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you seen [the solutions to a similar question over here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281509/how-do-i-change-the-screen-resolution-using-ubuntu-command-line)?

Comment: Is it possible to call it from the settings app? I don't want to use `xrandr`

Comment: Would you have any specific reason for not using xrandr?
Did you at least try it?

Comment: Yes I have tried it before, and I think it messed up with my display.