# which ubuntu version can ı use for 1024x600 resolution panel pc?

Tags: display-resolution

I have panel pc which had 1024x600 resolution.I couldn't find option on set screen on ubuntu 20.04.What is the solution for that or can you  suggest any ubuntu version to try?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the screen resolution using Ubuntu command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281509/how-do-i-change-the-screen-resolution-using-ubuntu-command-line)

Comment: I believe they all will, some desktops aren't as easy to use at that resolution until they've been configured, but I on occasion use 800x600, 1024x768 etc resolutions (*to test something looks good at that resolution for quality-assurance purposes*), but yes some resolutions do have issues with some user procedures so I'd opt probably for just a WM or the like (*if you can't find a desktop you're happy with at that resolution*).

Comment: I would recommend Ubuntu MATE with Netbook [panel layout](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/choosing-and-changing-panel-layouts-ubuntu-mate-18-04/16502).