# Difficulties installing Ubuntu using NOMODESET because the screen is too small - Continue Button not Visible

Tags: boot, nvidia, system-installation, graphics, live-usb

1. I am trying to install Ubuntu on my Laptop. It is my first time.
2. I used to have a [Black Screen during booting so used NOMODESET to successfully fix that, using the solution here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) This was probably due to Ubuntu not having drivers for my NVIDIA Graphics Card (?)
3. Ubuntu works fine in Live Mode otherwise (the Browser works, e.t.c), except that the screen is so small that **I cannot see all the options during installation + continue button.** (Photo Attached).

[image: Continue Button not visible]

4. Pressing ENTER does allow me to carry on to the next screen, but I'm not comfortable pressing ENTER blindly without knowing what options I have selected.

**Q. Is there a way to make the screen larger/install NVIDIA Graphics during installation? (Or can you recommend another way to install?) Thanks!**

Computer information:

- ASUS Zenbook UX431FN
- 16GB RAM
- Intel UHD Graphics 620
- NVIDIA Geforce MX150
- Windows 10 is the installed OS

**EDIT:I have tried the following and none have helped:**

1. Change the resolution with the Settings in GUI. There is only one option (800x600).[image]
2. See possible resolutions in the command line [using xrandr -q.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281509/how-do-i-change-the-screen-resolution-using-ubuntu-command-line) It says the Max is 800x600, and the Min is 800x600. Seems like I am locked in here?
3. Plug in an external monitor with HDMI. Nothing shows up on the external monitor automatically. The monitor's resolution is the same as my laptop's however (1920x1080), so I doubt it'll help much.
4. Just said "bugger it" and pressed the continue key blindly, until I reached the partitioning screen (photos attached). Here I can not even press "continue" by pressing enter, because it just selects the drop down box! So even using my keyboard I cannot continue forwards.
   [image]
   [image]

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu are you trying to install?

Comment: in 16.04 newer GPU's are not supported natively - but 19.xx works. As David asked, what version are you trying to install?

Comment: @David From the title bar: "Install Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS" .  Maybe try 22.04 and see if the problem persists.